# What is the "- +" in the redis timeseries commands?

Tags: redis, redistimeseries

I don't get the examples that have `- +` in the command. I'm probably missing something that is well-known and I'm just not aware/or know where to get the info but for example at https://redis.io/docs/stack/timeseries/quickstart/

They have command
`TS.RANGE sensor1 - + FILTER_BY_TS 1626435230501 1626443276598`

but I don't get what the `- +` is. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

The command format is: `TS.RANGE key fromTimestamp toTimestamp`

From the [doc](https://redis.io/commands/ts.range/):

> **fromTimestamp**
>
> is start timestamp for the range query. Use - to express the minimum possible timestamp (0).
>
> **toTimestamp**
>
> is end timestamp for the range query. Use + to express the maximum possible timestamp.

So in your case, it means DO NOT filter data by timestamp.

Comment: I see thanks. I just didn't know it was there. The quick start doesn't explain the `-`, `+`. I think they should at a minimum explain the symbols.

Answer (score 1):

[TS.RANGE](https://redis.io/commands/ts.range/), [TS.REVRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/ts.revrange/), [TS.MRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/ts.mrange/), and [TS.MREVRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/ts.mrevrange/) are range commands. You need to specify the range start and end timestamps.

Instead of specifying concrete values, you can you `-` and `+` respectively.

RedisTimeSeries replaces `-` with the timestamp of the earliest sample in the time series, and `+` with the timestamp of the latest sample in the time series.

Note that the query you composed

```
TS.RANGE sensor1 - + FILTER_BY_TS 1626435230501 1626443276598
```

would report samples only for two specific timestamps: 1626435230501 and 1626443276598, as `FILTER_BY_TS` is used for specifying a set of *exact* timestamps - **not a range** (to retrieve results, you must have samples with these exact timestamps, and these timestamps must fall within [`fromTimestamp` .. `toTimestamp`] which is [`-` .. `+`] in your case).

If you want to retrieve all samples between timestamp 1626435230501 and timestamp 1626443276598, you should instead use

```
TS.RANGE sensor1 1626435230501 1626443276598
```

And if you want to retrieve all samples in the time series, you can use

```
TS.RANGE sensor1 - +
```

Comment: Thanks! What about those that have another `+`? For example: `TS.RANGE sensor1 - + + AGGREGATION avg 3600000`?

Comment: In this case the second `+` is ignored and the command is equivalent to `TS.RANGE sensor1 - + AGGREGATION avg 3600000`. RedisTimeSeries silently ignores command-line arguments it can't parse (you'll get the same result for `TS.RANGE sensor1 - + foo bar AGGREGATION avg 3600000` )

Comment: ok thanks, just new to this so it wasn't obvious to me. Appreciate it.